# In excel how to create function to find a word in one column and place another word in different column

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I'm very new to excel, and I'm trying to figure this out...
If any cells in column A are empty or have the word 'EMPTY' I want it to generate the word 'EMPTY' into a cell in a different column.  For example: If A1 and A2 have the word 'EMPTY' in the cell, then I want the matching cell in column D to have that word as well (D1 and D2).

I have been messing around with =if(A2,EMPTY)(D2,EMPTY), but I'm clearly missing something.

I'm sorry if this has been asked, or is so simple, it's hard to phrase the exact wording to find a question that will give me an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example, in cell D1 use this formula and then copy it down:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A1,"*empty*")>0,A1=""),"EMPTY","NOT EMPTY")
```

You can replace the `"NOT EMPTY"` with the result of your choice for if the cell isn't empty, or you can just use `""` to return a blank result.

Comment: Thank you so much!  At first your formula entered "NOT EMPTY" into every cell that had something written in it, but I changed it to =IF(OR(COUNTIF(A1,"empty")>0,A1=""),"NOT EMPTY") and got the right stuff.  So thank you!  Is there a short explanation as to how this works? I get the (A1,"empty") part, but what does >0,A1="" do to the formula?  Thanks again!

Comment: The `COUNTIF` is for checking if a cell (or range of cells) contains a specific string.  If it does, the result will be a number greater than 0, and if it does not the result will be 0, so if it checks for "empty" and the result is greater than 0, or if the cell is blank, return "EMPTY", else return "NOT EMPTY"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="empty",""),"empty",0)
```

Assuming you've put "empty" in cell A1, or if the cell A1 is empty as well. You can then increment that formula from, say, B1 down to B10 (then B2 will be checked against A2, B3 against A3, etc).

As a general rule, in Excel, if in the formular bar you start typing

```
=IF(
```

Then there will be a small drop-down text that will give you a clue as to what to write next...